# Windows 7 CPU usage after update

Tags: windows-7, operating-systems, cpu-usage, anti-virus, task-manager

After windows 7 updated and restarted it shows 98-100% CPU usage in task manager. But, it doesn't show any heavy process or thread using it. Are they hidden processes that the task manager doesn't display.

even when I clicked a button **`display processes from all users`** it doesn't show any like this. And I am pretty sure that there are no viruses as Antivirus updates daily. **But, can it be a Virus processes that usually task manager can't display? this can be another question inspite.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Show processes for all users" should show everything. See also the Resource Manager (startable from Task Manager) to get more info.

Btw, it's probably indexing or somesuch service. Just wait an hour or so and CPU usage should drop to normal levels.

Comment: it dropped to normal level just after a minute. still sometime CPU usage goes higher suddenly like up-down in high range.

Comment: The resource manager is usually more effective at displaying "hidden" stuff.

Comment: Also, [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) gives you even more detailed CPU usage information that you can use to drill down to find out exactly what is sucking cycles.

Comment: Thanks @Mracus Lindblom : I got it from Resource Monitor. It is **MsMpEng.exe** an `antimalware service executable` of Microsoft Security Essentials.

Comment: @maniclorn: I'm glad that it helped. Please accept the answer to record that your problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

There is normally a button that says "Show processes from all users" or something similar to that.

Try ticking that and see if it shows the offending process.